# Android AlertDialog freezes when saving data in database

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

In my App my I am using AlertDialog in Async. But it freezes at a point when data is saving in database. what can I do to keep it running? It runs perfectly for sometime but stops after certain time when database is accessed.

Here's my code:

```
class BackGroundTasks extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void> {
@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        if (dialog == null) {
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(mActivity, null,
                    "Please wait ...", true);

        }

    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        CheckInternetConnection internet = new CheckInternetConnection(
                mActivity);
        if (!internet.HaveNetworkConnection()) {
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        super.onPostExecute(result);
        try {
            CheckInternetConnection internet = new CheckInternetConnection(
                    getApplicationContext());
            if (!internet.HaveNetworkConnection()) {
                showToast("No Internet Connection.");
                return;
            } else {
         setUpdatedBarcodes();
           }
           }
           }
           }

        private boolean setUpdatedBarcodes(
            ArrayList<Model_BarcodeDetail> changedBarcodeList2) {

        try {
            int i = 0;
            BarcodeDatabase barcodeDatabase = new  
            BarcodeDatabase(mActivity);
            barcodeDatabase.open();
            for (Model_BarcodeDetail model : changedBarcodeList2) {
                barcodeDatabase.updateEntry(model, userId);
            }

            barcodeDatabase.close();
            if (RefList1.equals(RefList)) {

                if (dialog != null) {
                    dialog.dismiss();  // cancelling Async dialog here after  
                                          data is saved in DB
                }
                showToast("Barcodes updated successfully");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("Exception caught in: ", "setDownloadedBarcodes method");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true;

    }
```

Comment: does it show any errors?? can you share the log cat??

Comment: It does not show any error. AlertDialog just stops progressing.

Comment: one thing is that you are not utilizing the AsyncTask correctly. You should move setUpdatedbarCodes() to doInBackground

Comment: @SheenaTyagi: Do DB operations and internet connection check inside `doInBackground`

Comment: `I am using AlertDialog in Async.`  ??  There is no AlertDialog in your code.

Answer (score 0):

DB operations should be done in the background thread. Put it in `doInBackground()` method too.

Answer (score 0):

when saving data in database don't do it on main thread do it on background thread. try code

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
         // do your work
     }
},0);
```

or

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
         // do your work here
    }
}).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

I modify your code. may it helps..

```
class BackGroundTasks extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void> {
@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        if (dialog == null) {
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(mActivity, null,
                    "Please wait ...", true);
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        CheckInternetConnection internet = new CheckInternetConnection(
                mActivity);
        if (!internet.HaveNetworkConnection()) {
            showToast("No Internet Connection.");
        } else {
            setUpdatedBarcodes();
        }
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (dialog != null) {
             dialog.dismiss();  // cancelling Async dialog here
        }
    }
}

private boolean setUpdatedBarcodes(
     ArrayList<Model_BarcodeDetail> changedBarcodeList2) {
        try {
            int i = 0;
            BarcodeDatabase barcodeDatabase = new  
            BarcodeDatabase(mActivity);
            barcodeDatabase.open();
            for (Model_BarcodeDetail model : changedBarcodeList2) {
                barcodeDatabase.updateEntry(model, userId);
            }

            barcodeDatabase.close();
            if (RefList1.equals(RefList)) {
                showToast("Barcodes updated successfully");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("Exception caught in: ", "setDownloadedBarcodes method");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```